# Is the Wistron NeWeb DNUB-236 supported on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, driver

I have a Wistron NeWeb DNUB-236 USB wifi dongle, which has the Broadcom BCM43236 chip onboard. I got it to work on my ubuntu system by using the `brcmfmac` driver.

Is this driver supported on Raspbian? Is there any other way to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

There's source for building brcmfmac.ko in the rpi specific ["3.6.y" source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux).   I've built kernels for use with raspbian using this source with a cross-compiler; building it on the pi will be easier but take a very long time, I think.

I don't have the 3.2.27+ source that represents the raspbian default, but presumably it is in that too.  However, the 3.6.y default build doesn't include the brcmfmac module for some reason (it includes most of the other available wifi drivers), so it may not be installed in raspbian.

Make sure about which kernel you are running with `uname -r`.

Your best bet is to just plug in the dongle (actually, plug it in before you power up, as wifi dongles tend to cause a sudden voltage drop when inserted into the pi, cutting the power momentarily) and try:

```
lsmod | grep brcmfmac
```

If that doesn't show anything:

```
modprobe brcmfmac
```

And if that doesn't work, you can look in `/lib/modules/3.2.27+/kernel/drivers/wireless` to confirm that it isn't there.  In this case, you can build a 3.2.27+ module on the pi without rebuilding the whole kernel (presuming the source for it is in the 3.2.27+ tree).

Comment: How exactly do you build it? A link with instructions would be great :D